# Can we increase spectral norms of All maximum size square submatrices by orthogonal perturbation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let the matrix $A$ consist of $k$ columns from some $n \times n$ orthogonal (unitary) matrix. It is obvious that there is no perturbation of $A$ which

- leaves its columns orthonormal,
- increases **Frobenius** norms of **all** its $k \times k$ submatrices.

Does this fact remain true for **spectral** norm?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by a perturbation?

Comment: Here I mean any other matrix of the same size with orthonormal columns.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.